# Java.lang.integer to int: Is it possible?

Tags: android

Java.lang.integer to int: Is it possible?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.anatomi1);
    Dersadi=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t_dersadi);
    Soru=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t_soru);

    btncvp1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_cvp1);
    btncvp2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_cvp2);
    btncvp3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_cvp3);
    btncvp4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_cvp4);
    btncvp5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_cvp5);

    btncvp1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btncvp2.setOnClickListener(this);
    btncvp3.setOnClickListener(this);
    btncvp4.setOnClickListener(this);
    btncvp5.setOnClickListener(this);

    db=openOrCreateDatabase("Soru", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sorular(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,ders VARCHAR,soru VARCHAR,cevap1 VARCHAR,cevap2 VARCHAR,cevap3 VARCHAR,cevap4 VARCHAR,cevap5 VARCHAR,puan VARCHAR);");
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM sorular WHERE ders = 'Anatomi' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", null);
    List<Integer> btnlari = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 3; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        btnlari.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(btnlari);
    pint1 = btnlari.get(1);
    pint2 = btnlari.get(2);
    pint3 = btnlari.get(3);
    pint4 = btnlari.get(4);
    pint5 = btnlari.get(5);
    if(c.moveToFirst())
    {
        Dersadi.setText(c.getString(1));
        Soru.setText(c.getString(2));
        btncvp1.setText(c.getString(pint1));
        btncvp2.setText(c.getString(pint2));
        btncvp3.setText(c.getString(pint3));
        btncvp4.setText(c.getString(pint4));
        btncvp5.setText(c.getString(pint5));
    }
}
```

I can try to get randomly values in sql db but java lang integer not usable maybe?

can anyone help me how to get sql db columns randomly in buttons?

Comment: Please, show your full code of class?

Comment: I can trying but they want more words to describe I cant put full code. Its enough ?

Comment: I do not fully understand what you want. Why integer not usable? What class instances pint1,pint2...?

Comment: Class Integer casting to int automatically.

Comment: I want to make quiz app I make 5 answer randomly given buttons but I dont know how to do it

Comment: I make btnlari integer list between 3-7 because answers is in sql column 3-7 and I put numbers btnlari and shuffle numbers to randomly given pint1 2 3 .
pint1 is first button pint2 second answers randomly given buttons.

Comment: Your variables pint1, pint2, pint3 is int?

Comment: public class Anatomi1 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView Dersadi, Soru;
    Button btncvp1, btncvp2, btncvp3, btncvp4, btncvp5;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    private String cevap_d = "1";
    private int pint1 = 0;
    private int pint2 = 0;
    private int pint3 = 0;
    private int pint4 = 0;
    private int pint5 = 0;
yes upside oncreate

Comment: And your application crashes?

Comment: there `pint5 = btnlari.get(5);` you get error?

Comment: why others work but not 5 ?

Comment: array index starts from 0

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem as follows:

```
pint1 = btnlari.get(0);
pint2 = btnlari.get(1);
pint3 = btnlari.get(2);
pint4 = btnlari.get(3);
pint5 = btnlari.get(4);
```

Comment: Thanks I understand now